# How can I change Nautilus's delete behavior?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, finder, nautilus

I want to make it so that nautilus requires me to press a key combination to delete files - so that I do not accidentally delete files on a network share with no confirmation again.

Ideally I would make the behavior identical to OSX's Finder, so that I press ctrl+backspace to delete files.

Answer (score 0):

By default `nautilus` does ask for conformation before removing local or remote files. To bypass this one uses `SHIFT-DEL`.

If you accidentally disabled this, you can re-enable it in the `nautilus` preferences. In any `nautilus` window: Edit -> Preferences -> Behavior -> "Ask before ...".

Comment: It was and is not disabled, and I do not get any confirmation when deleting files.  They go straight to trash.  (or if a network file, they are 'permanently' deleted)

Comment: Simply: The answer given is wrong. Checking "Ask before ..." only refers to the process of emptying the trash. But the issue here is asking before a file is put to the trash.